# Is there any way to pop up softphone screen from data coming from REST API?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, rest-api, opencti, softphone

I have developed Open CTI lightning (softphone) in Salesforce as a pop up for incoming and outgoing call. I am facing this problem as the telephone system vendor they do not have adapter to communicate with Salesforce.

What I have done is, I have created one REST API service for them to send phone number and data through this service to Salesforce.

I want to know that is there anyway to trigger screen to pop up from the data send through REST API as an incoming call or is there any other way to overcome this requirement.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm)? It let's you stream events and therefore react to the data updates.

Comment: Hi Blank,
Thank you for your comment I have looked into Streaming API but still did not meet my requirement yet.

I am working on the other way around where search result page should be open once the data has been sent through REST API.
Do you have any idea on how to do this ?